# How to insert data into created_at and updated_at columns in a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-migration

I created some tables (Users, Posts, Likes, and Comments) in a Postgres database using migrations in a Rails application.
There are two auto generated columns (created_at and updated_at) in all my tables.

Now I am going to pgAdmin to manually add some users, but I do not know what to write in (created_at and updated_at) columns.

After some researches I found out that if I write "now" there, it will add the current time, but the problem is when I update a comment or post the time in updated_at column always stays the same.

Comment: `update ... set updated_at = current_timestamp, ... where ...`?

Comment: Do you mean I should set the default value of my columns to current_timestamp?

Comment: No, you need to include that column when you run your UPDATE statement.

Comment: This just begs the question why you think you want to insert the data using PG Admin instead of for example using `seeds.rb` to insert the data through ActiveRecord? Stop making life difficult for yourself.

Comment: @max Thank you, that was helpful
I just started learning Rails and I just came to know how to use seeds.